# IE7 and IE8 visibility issue

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am facing a weird problem firstly the ribbon is visible but as I scroll down the jquery transition makes the navigation bar visible but ribbon went.

Its working fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE9+ but not in IE7 and IE8.

http://toplevel.toplevelnetworking.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably just js errors are causing IE to stop working.  

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutQuart'

that js error shows in chrome btw.

Comment: Error: c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || b] is not a function
Source File: http://toplevel.toplevelnetworking.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4
Line: 155

I see that in Firefox. Maybe this error is rbeaking things more in IE, or not at all, but it's always good to eliminate all errors when debugging.

I've run into issues with opacity in IE before, that might be involved.

Also IE can reset the z-index of some positioned elements. It might help if you try and manually set the z-index of the navigation on the "show" event.

Answer (score 0):

First off, that's pretty cool :). It's kind of tricky for me to quickly get an understanding of your HTML structure. But I bet it's a z-index issue. I see you have the containing div of the ribbon set to position absolute and z-index:999. That's great. For stuff you want it ontop of, set to position relative (or absolute if you need to, just make sure it's one of the two). And set the z-index to something lower, such as 1.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding what we are referring to, then perhaps building this site is a bit above your skill level. It might not hurt to ask a friend or someone that can help you in person figure it out. That said, what we're basically talking about is applying the CSS z-index rule to try and get around a bug/issue with IE.